# ssis import xml attributes as elements

Tags: sql, xml, xslt, ssis, sql-server-2016

I have the following (this is just a sample) xml that is received from a third party (and we have no influence on changing the structure) that we need to import to SQL Server. Each of these files have multiple top level nodes (excuse me if the terminology is incorrect, but I mean the "CardAuthorisation" element). So some are CardFee, Financial etc etc

The issue is that the detail is in attributes. This file is from a new vendor. There is an xml file currently being received from another vendor which is a lot easier to import as the data is in elements and not in attributes.

Here is a sample:

```
    <CardAuthorisation>
    <RecType>ADV</RecType>
    <AuthId>32397275</AuthId>
    <AuthTxnID>11606448</AuthTxnID>
    <LocalDate>20140612181918</LocalDate>
    <SettlementDate>20140612</SettlementDate>
    <Card PAN="2009856214560271" product="MCRD" programid="DUMMY1" branchcode=""></Card>
    <Account no="985621456" type="00"></Account>
    <TxnCode direction="debit" Type="atm" Group="fee" ProcCode="30" Partial="NA" FeeWaivedOff="0"></TxnCode>
    <TxnAmt value="0.0000" currency="826"></TxnAmt>
    <CashbackAmt value="0.00" currency="826"></CashbackAmt>
    <BillAmt value="0.00" currency="826" rate="1.00"></BillAmt>
    <ApprCode>476274</ApprCode>
    <Trace auditno="305330" origauditno="305330" Retrefno="061200002435"></Trace>
    <MerchCode>BOIA           </MerchCode>
    <Term code="S1A90971" location="PO NORFOLK STR 3372308 CAMBRIDGESHI3 GBR" street="" city="" country="GB" inputcapability="5" authcapability="7"></Term>
    <Schema>MCRD</Schema>
    <Txn cardholderpresent="0" cardpresent="yes" cardinputmethod="5" cardauthmethod="1" cardauthentity="1"></Txn>
    <MsgSource value="74" domesticMaestro="yes"></MsgSource>
    <PaddingAmt value="0.00" currency="826"></PaddingAmt>
    <Rate_Fee value="0.00"></Rate_Fee>
    <Fixed_Fee value="0.20"></Fixed_Fee>
    <CommissionAmt value="0.20" currency="826"></CommissionAmt>
    <Classification RCC="" MCC="6011"></Classification>
    <Response approved="YES" actioncode="0" responsecode="00" additionaldesc=" PO NORFOLK STR 3372308 CAMBRIDGESHI3 GBR"></Response>
    <OrigTxnAmt value="0.00" currency="826"></OrigTxnAmt>
    <ReversalReason></ReversalReason>
</CardAuthorisation>
```

And what we need to do is be able to import this to various tables (one for each top level element type).

So for example CardAuthorisation should be imported to the "Authorisation" table, the CardFinancial should go to the "Financial" table etc.

So the question is what is the best method to employ to import this data.

Having read a bit, I understand xslt can be used for this and would be able to make the above into:

```
<CardAuthorisation>
    <RecType>ADV</RecType>
    <AuthId>32397275</AuthId>
    <AuthTxnID>11606448</AuthTxnID>
    <LocalDate>20140612181918</LocalDate>
    <SettlementDate>20140612</SettlementDate>
    <PAN>"2009856214560271"</PAN> 
    <product>MCRD</product>
    <programid>DUMMY1</programid>
    <branchcode>1</branchcode>
    <Accountno>"985621456"</Accountno>
    <type>"00"</type>
    <TxnCodedirection>"debit"</TxnCodedirection
    <TxnCodeType>"atm" </TxnCodeType>
    <TxnCodeGroup>"fee" </TxnCodeGroup>
    <TxnCodeProcCode>"30" </TxnCodeProcCode>
    <TxnCodePartial>"NA" </TxnCodePartial>
    <TxnCodeFeeWaivedOff>"0"</TxnCodeFeeWaivedOff>
    <TxnAmtvalue>"0.0000"</TxnAmtvalue>
    <TxnAmtcurrency>"826"</TxnAmtcurrency>
    <CashbackAmtvalue>"0.00"</CashbackAmtvalue>
    <CashbackAmtcurrency>"826"</CashbackAmtcurrency>
    <BillAmtvalue>"0.00" </BillAmtvalue>
    <BillAmtcurrency>"826" </BillAmtcurrency>
    <BillAmtrate=>1.00"></BillAmtrate>
    <ApprCode>476274</ApprCode>
    etc etc
</CardAuthorisation>
```

But the info I read was quite old (4-5 yrs old) and I know SSIS is always being improved so not sure if it was still valid advice today?

Thanks in advance for your thoughts.

Comment: What are you actually asking?  Yes, you can certainly write an XSLT stylesheet that transforms attributes in the input document to elements in the output document, but it looks like you probably want something a bit more tuned to your data than just doing that universally.

Comment: I guess the question is: Is there a better, quicker and more appropriate way of doing this other than XSLT? And if so, what is/are the option(s)

Comment: If *that's* the question then it is too broad for SO, and it moreover borders on being primarily-opinion based.